# Save content from dynamically generated integer up downs to a list

Tags: c#, wpf

My app is asking user to input a number of items, which generates that many IntegerUpDown controls in a StackPanel. The user must choose a number in each of them. Then, I want to save those values into a list. How do I construct this and save date from changing number of items?

```
for(int i=0; i< numberOfItems; i++)
{
    iud=new IntegerUpDown();
    stackPanel1.Children.Add(iud);
}
```

This part works fine but I don't know how to bind this changeable number of IntegerUpDowns controls to some list and get all the values at once.

```
<StackPanel Name="stackPanel1" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1">     
</StackPanel>
```

Example: user inputs 3 and this generates 3 IntegerUpDowns. Then the user inputs 5, 14, 38 in each IntegerUpDown. I want to save those numbers in the `List<int>`.

I hope this is not too confusing. I don't know terminology so well so I don't know how to look for the solution to this problem.

Comment: You are so incredibly far from the correct solution to your problem that I am voting to close your question as being too broad. In the mean time, please read the [Walkthrough: Getting Started with WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms752299(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Data Templating Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521(v=vs.110).aspx) pages from MSDN to get a better idea on how WPF is *actually* written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get all the controls from the StackPanel that are of the type `IntegerUpDown`. Then, loop over them and get their value. In below code, `ControlsStackPanel` is the name of the StackPanel.

```
var values = new List<int>();
var children = ControlsStackPanel.Children.OfType<IntegerUpDown>();

foreach (var child in children)
{
    values.Add(child.Value.Value);
}
```

Or shorter:

```
var values = new List<int>();

foreach (var child in ControlsStackPanel.Children.OfType<IntegerUpDown>())
    values.Add(child.Value.Value);
```

Or even in one line using LinQs `Select`:

```
var values = ControlsStackPanel.Children
                               .OfType<IntegerUpDown>()
                               .Select(x => x.Value.Value);
```

Note the double `.Value`. This is because the value of the IntegerUpDown is a `nullable integer` and the second `.Value` gets the integer value of that nullable. If the IntegerUpDown doesn't have a value and you call this, you'll get an `InvalidOperationException` when trying to add it to the list!